# Couchbase query - different results

Tags: c#, couchbase

I am using a .NET client of Couchbase and I facing this problem:

```
var items = client.Get(originalOrder);
```

originalOrder is an IEnumerable, with all the record ID's in it (around 300k) and I want to get all the records. The problem is, that I'm not getting all the records, and the number of the result is different after every query (150k-200k). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it already. The project needed to be in x64 build mode and I am getting all the results now.

Answer (score 0):

Just, see below.(from couchbase dev guide doc [here](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/cb-get-one-key.html).)

> If you have an error with the size of your value or formatting, you need to check the value itself, and how it is encoded and see if there are any issues that make the document incompatible with Couchbase Server.

And you can check more detaily using [`object.ExcuteGet(key)`](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-net-1.2/#retrieve-operations)

```
var result = client.ExecuteGet("beer");
if (! result.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Get failed with message {0} and status code {1}", result.Message, result.StatusCode);
   ...
```